# Процедура Split

Tags: delphi

Можете подсказать почему когда я ввожу к примеру '123 456&123', процедура `split` выдает 3 строки: 123 456 123, хотя я думал что будет 2, ведь разделитель один... Как быть чтоб пробел не читал за разделитель?.. Спасибо)

```
procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter     := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText := Str;
end;

var
   OutPutList: TStringList;
begin
   OutPutList := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Split('&', '123 456&123', OutPutList) ;
     Writeln(OutPutList.Text);
     Readln;
    finally
     OutPutList.Free;
   end;
end.
```

Comment: Если лень решать эту проблему, то напиши подпорку: замени пробел на любую последоватьность символов, например, "#SPACE#", а после разделения замени "#SPACE#" обратно на пробелы (функция StringReplace). Но это не решение, а только подпорка :)

Comment: @Alisa это не то что подпорка… это… это… это просто жесть какая-то о_0.

Comment: Ну, эта из тех подпорок, что можно применять, если под дулом пистолета :) Если есть хоть небольшой шанс на обходной путь, то надо просто написать самостоятельно этот сплит несчастный. Тем более, что разделитель один и из одного символа, так что это совсем уж элементарно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо выставить

ListOfStrings.StrictDelimiter : = True;

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStrings.StrictDelimiter

Поскольку в старом дельфи нет реализации Split вообще, то придётся либо писать её самому, либо брать готовую. Вот, например, на SO обсуждение этой проблемы и некоторые решения: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625707/delphi-how-do-i-split-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-based-on-a-delimiter

Хотя, ИМХО, учитывая ваши скилы, вам было бы полезно для тренировки написать это самостоятельно.

Общая схема следующая: 
ищете подстроку Delimiter в исходной строке.. если находите, то вырезаете всё от начала (или предыдущего конца) до той позиции, где нашли подстроку. Вырезанный фрагмент кладёте в список строк (в результат). Если не находится подстрока, то добавляете всё оставшееся в результирующий список.

Comment: А где именно? пишет что "Undeclared identifier: 'StrictDelimiter'..."

Comment: О, похоже у вас какой-то страный Delphi. В старом Delphi вам придётся писать split самостятельно, чтобы получить наконец нормальный результат.

Comment: И как ещё народ продолжает упорствовать и писать на этом чуде, я просто диву даюсь..

Comment: Ясно всё... у меня DElphi 7  Какую среду лучше установить? RAD Studio 2010?.. Самостоятельно.. Я бы написал, если бы знал что и как делать;) Лан попрбую...

Comment: Лучше напишите split сами: для вас это будет хорошим упражнением ;)

Comment: Хорошо.. Не подскажите с чего начать хотя бы?.. И как быть дальше?... Я же всего лишь учусь, тяжеловато приходится в некоторых моментах...

Comment: Разберитесь, как работать со строками. Как найти подстроку в строке, как выделить подстроку из строки. Разберитесь как работать с массивами. Научитесь класть выделенные подстроки в массив.  Можете для простоты добавлять не в массив, а в TStrings.

Comment: Вообще, если бы вы меня послушали, то ничего бы этого не было. Этот ваш split таит в себе массу опасностей.

Comment: Источник по какой теме?

Comment: В каком месте я вас ослушался?... Про MVC... Сложно для меня.. По крайней мере я даже не знаю как это реализовать?.. А так если бы знал то сделал... Ни книг, ни примеров ничего нет... Как говорит наш завкаф "уровень вашего программирования на уровне городской канализации..." Хотя специальность включает в ся знание С++, а я тока с каркасом приложения знаком.. Потому что это только читали... Может быть лет через 10 я стану "истинным джедаем"...

Comment: Про работу со строками...и т.п...

Comment: MVC это отдельная история и от него вам не убежать :) Про "ослушался" я имел в виду, что вы стали использовать текстовый разделитель для отделения полей. Я так понимаю, что первое поле - это имя конторы, а остальное данные? Отлично. Представте себе, что у вас большо коммерческое приложение и его юзают много клиентов. И вдруг.. нарисовалась компания K&R Corporation.. они смело вводят своё имя в форму.. а у вас БА-БАХ.. и компания зовётся K, а в данные пролезло R Comrporation. Вот беда.. и заказчики огорчатся, и K&R..

Comment: Да я это представлял... Эт будет ж**а... Так как быть то бедному незнайке? Прост люди попросили, я сказал что сделаю, пока все получается, но вот загвоздка с разделением, и я думаю они еще будут и будут - эти "проблемки".. Не охото так же людей подводить, да и для меня это первый опыт... Я еще на стадии обсуждения сказал что могут возникнуть проблемы в "сфере знаний", из за которых все полетит к чертям...((

Comment: 'проблемы в "сфере знаний", из за которых все полетит к чертям' - прекрасная формулировка.. возьму на вооружение :) Про разделение, я уже говорил: самое простое и при этом надёжное, это использовать XML.

Comment: http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/xml_use.html, что скажите про этот источник об XML, или есть что то другое?... Более понятное и подходящее для моего варианта?...

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure MySplit(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings);
var
    PStart:PChar;
    PEnd:PChar;
begin
    PEnd:=PChar(Str);
    while PEnd<>#0 do
    begin
        PStart:=PEnd;
        while not (PEnd in [#0,Delimiter]) do inc(PEnd);
        //if PEnd>PStart then // позволять пустые строки?
            ListOfString.Add(Copy(PStart,0,PEnd-PStart));
        If PEnd^=Delimiter then Inc(PEnd);
    end;
end;
```

Как-то так.

PS Ставьте Delphi XE или просто поновее... там дженерик и другие вкусности.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string): TStrings;
var
  i: Integer;
  row: string;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  i := 1;
  row := '';
  while i <= Length(Str) do
  begin
    if (Str[i] = Delimiter) then
    begin
      Result.Add(row);
      row := '';
    end
    else
      row := row + Str[i];
    i := i + 1;
  end;
  if (row <> '') then
    Result.Add(row);
end;
```

Мой вариант с односимвольным разделителем.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses System.Types, System.StrUtils;

procedure getfoldernamefrompath(pt: string); // as Example
var
  sdas: TStringDynArray;
begin
 sdas := SplitString( pt,PathDelim); // pathdelim or other char. pt - search string

  if sdas[0] = '' then 
    ...
end;
```