# Парсинг и вывод значения из value

Tags: delphi

```
function Pars(T_, ForS, _T:string):string;   //Функция парсинга
   var a, b:integer;
   begin
      Result := '';
      if (T_='') or (ForS='') or (_T='') 
         then Exit;
      a:=Pos(T_, ForS);
      if a=0 
         then Exit else a:=a+Length(T_);
      ForS:=Copy(ForS, a, Length(ForS)-a+1);
      b:=Pos(_T, ForS);
      if b>0 then
         Result:=Copy(ForS, 1, b - 1);
   end; 

var
  tokin, name:string ;

begin
    tokin := idhtp1.Get('http://сайт.ru/');
    name := Pars('<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value=',tokin,' name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN"></div>');
    lbl2.Caption:=('=================' + #13#10 + 'Имя: ' + name + #13#10 + '=================');
    mmo1.Lines.Add(tokin);
end;
```

Подскажите как вывести значение из value. Выше код парсинга и как пробовал вывести.

Comment: Что вообще записано после value?

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="c4a1f3104786b3cb874aa622a344aa0543178e12" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN"> пример,

Comment: @Cfg.JS нужно парсить значение переменной **name** которая содержит результат функции **Pars**.

Comment: @айтишник Я подозреваю что функция `Pars` должна возвратить `c4a1f3104786b3cb874aa622a344aa0543178e12`. @Cfg.JS задал вопрос - как вывести значение из value.

Comment: @androschuk, но судя по вопросу - это значение он получает со стороны. Таким образом непонятно зачем ему вообще нужен парс, чтобы получить это значение из строки, в которую он его сам же и вставил?

Comment: @androschuk, вообще судя по примеру, я бы предположил что `Pars` должна была вернуть _YII_CSRF_TOKEN_ то есть значение атрибут name, так как и переменная в которую присваивается результат функции названа Name, и выводится она как `Имя`.

Comment: @Grundy Может быть изначально так и было. tokin - это входная строка `<input type="hidden" value="c4a1f3104786b3cb874aa622a344aa0543178e12" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN">`, а два остальных аргумента `<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value=` и ` name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN"></div>` это то что он хотел отсечь для поиска Value. Как то так. Вот что бывает когда неправильно подобрать названия переменных. Только сбивают с толку.

Comment: @androschuk, вот из-за этих додумываний, что именно хотел спросить автор вопрос и могут минусовать :)

Comment: @Grundy, так ничего додумывать не нужно было, есть четкий вопрос в низу поста. А то что переменные названы неправильно - это реальный прокол и всех завел в заблуждение. Да я погорячился, извиняюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается ответа на вопрос:

```
Uses
  StrUtils;

function Parse(AText, StartToken, EndToken : string): string;
var
    StrartPos : Integer;
    StrartTokenPos : Integer;
    EndPos : Integer;
begin
    Result := EmptyStr;

    StrartPos := Pos(StartToken, AText);
    If StrartPos <= 0 Then
        Exit;
    StrartTokenPos := StrartPos + Length(StartToken);

    EndPos := PosEx(EndToken, AText, StrartTokenPos);

    If EndPos <= 0 Then
        Result := Copy(AText, StrartTokenPos, Length(AText) - StrartPos - 1)
    Else
        Result := Copy(AText, StrartTokenPos, EndPos - StrartTokenPos);
end;

// Использование
var
  Value : string ;
сonst
  InputText = '<input type="hidden" value="c4a1f3104786b3cb874aa622a344aa0543178e12" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN">';
begin
  Value := Parse(InputText, 'value="', '"');
end;
```

Данный пример заточен под текущую задачу. Функция возвращает значение между `value="` и `"`. Модуль `StrUtils` подключил для того чтобы можно было воспользоваться функцией `PosEx`.

Кстати Ваш вариант тоже рабочий, только нужно было передать немного другие аргументы.

```
Value := Pars2('<input type="hidden" value="',InputText,'" name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN">');
```

Но если изменится разметка, или добавится где то пробел - функция работать не будет.

Comment: а в Delphi был какой-то инструментарий для регулярок?

Comment: Конечно есть. Если ранние версии, можно воспользоваться [TRegExpr](http://regexpstudio.com/RU/TRegExpr/TRegExpr.html) или. [TPerlRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html). 
Начиная с Delphi XE, RTL поддерживает регулярные выражения 'с коробки' [docwiki.embarcadero.com](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/VCL_and_RTL_Changes_for_XE)

Comment: может в таком случае лучше их использовать? для такого простого случая они вполне подойдут, чем городушки с позиционированием и копированием. Ну или хотя бы `Split` и потом так же пробежаться. я надеюсь Split добавили?

Comment: Вполне подойдет. Остается написать грамотную реализацию. Со `Split'ом` для старой версии с помощью `StringList'а` подробности [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3890/2110). И если не ошибаюсь с `Delphi XE3` появился `TStringHelper` с методом `Split` [пример](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split)

Comment: ээээх, совсем новые версии не видел :-)

Comment: Да они их выпускаю с такой скоростью что не успеваешь устанавливать :-)