# Разделить строку в Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, split

Есть строка S и массив строк:

```
var
  S: string;
  words: array of string;
begin
  ReadLn(S);
  words := S.Split(' ');
end;
```

При компиляции выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии такой перегрузки у Split.
Какую перегрузку Split стоит использовать, чтобы в массиве строк получить все слова по порядку?

Текст ошибки:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(68): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Split' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки целиком, пожалуйста.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Процедура Split](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3888/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-split)

Comment: Какую перегрузку Split стоит использовать, чтобы в массиве строк получить все слова по порядку?

Comment: @slippyk не дубликат. Вопрос про конкретную функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно заглянуть в [хелп](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/fr/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Split) и увидеть, что все версии возвращают `TArray<string>` , а первым аргументом идёт **массив** (символов или строк), а не просто строка или символ

```
words: TArray<string>;

words := S.Split([' ']);
```